# Django how to order an object based on a related field

Tags: python, django

The following code is used to determine the order of objects as they get dumped to JSON. It also allows the datatables jquery plug in to set by which column the order is being established, and if its ascending or descending. This works great for the default ordering of objects, but what if I want to order an object based on a related field? How would I do that?

```
objects = StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=store_id)
keys = ['SPI', 'liquorID']

#sorting
order = dict( enumerate(keys) )
dirs = {'asc': '', 'desc': '-'}
ordering = dirs[request.GET['sSortDir_0']] + order[int(request.GET['iSortCol_0'])]
objects = objects.order_by(ordering)
```

With this code, it will sort just fine based on the `liquourID` which is a foreign key. But how could I get it to sort alphabetically based on `BrandName`, a field in the table that `liquourID` references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out on my own, how to do this. I'm not sure if its the best solution, but implementing if and then statements does work. since `enumerate(keys)` assigns an integer to each key in `keys`, and the request for the pressed column to be sorted also returns an int, I set it to change that order based on if its ascending or descending, and if the second column was pressed.

```
#sorting
order = dict( enumerate(keys) )
direction = request.GET['sSortDir_0']
column = request.GET['iSortCol_0']
dirs = {'asc': '', 'desc': '-'}
if direction == 'asc' and column == '1':
    ordering = dirs[direction] + order[int(column)]
    objects = objects.order_by('liquorID__BrandName')
elif direction == 'desc' and column == '1':
    ordering = dirs[direction] + order[int(column)]
    objects = objects.order_by('-liquorID__BrandName')
else:
    ordering = dirs[direction] + order[int(column)]
    objects = objects.order_by(ordering)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same style of syntax as you would with `filter` to query across relations.

e.g.

```
objects = objects.order_by('tablename__BrandName')
```

Where `tablename` is the name of the *Foreign Key* field.

From the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by):

> To order by a field in a different model, use the same syntax as when
>   you are querying across model relations. That is, the name of the
>   field, followed by a double underscore (__), followed by the name of
>   the field in the new model, and so on for as many models as you want
>   to join.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

Based on your response that you want to sort by both the selected column in *Datatables* **and** `BrandName`, I think you would want to pass both as arguments to `order_by` (which takes multiple arguments to order by successive columns in *SQL*):

```
objects = objects.order_by(ordering, 'tablename__BrandName')
```

Or reverse the arguments, depending on which column you want to take precedence.

Comment: I've already tried that, it doesn't change anything for the sorting in the table, since it still only looks for the liquorID field and searches by that.

Comment: What does the generated query look like after the changed `order_by`? Call `print` on `objects.query` and you should see the output in the terminal where `runserver` is running. What if you also add the extra FK to `filter` and then also call `select_related`?

Comment: If I set the order_by how you have it, in the sorting section, Then it will sort by the brand name. However, it destroys all the functionality the code provides, such as allow it to sort in reverse, or allowing it to be sorted by different objects.

Comment: I thought you wanted to override the default behavior? Do you want to sort by the brand name in addition to whatever column has been selected? If you click-to-sort in *Datatables* on a specific column, then that will by defintion be on a single column, in whichever direction is specified.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want. But I have it modified to give me the the BrandName instead of the liquor code. But I can't seem to get it to sort by the BrandName.